# How much current is needed for a hall sensor to detect a HIGH signal?

Tags: arduino, current, brushless-dc-motor, hall-effect

I am trying to get a sensored bldc motor to spin by building my own ESC (electric speed controller).

I have built a circuit that works perfectly the way I want it to using 3 H bridges, but the problem I am having is the hall sensors aren't detecting any signals when I apply current through the motor. Because the sensors don't detect anything my circuit doesn't know when to switch phases and therefore no spinning occurs.

The motor that I have is rated for 18-42 volts, but I am scared to put 18 volts on my motor without knowing if it will spin because even at 5 volts there is already ~3 amps flowing through my circuit and I feel like something is gonna burn up if I apply 18 volts. I want to make sure my hall sensors work before sending 18V. For reference I have my hall sensors hooked up to +5 volts on my arduino, while the motor is hooked up to a separate DC power supply. Here is the [schematic](http://electronoobs.com/images/Circuitos/tut_19/sch_3.png) I am following:

[image]

When I apply 5 volts and ~3 amps through the motor and try to get a reading using the `digitalRead(sensorPin)` function, all 3 of my sensors only return a low signal so I don't know what phase to put the motor in.

**Question:**

Is my problem that I am not applying enough voltage / current for the hall sensors to detect something? Or is it most likely something else? If it is something else any suggestions?

Comment: The Hall sensors sense the spinning magnets on the rotor. If they aren't spinning ... no output. To test them, spin the rotor by hand.You may need to start the motor open-loop for a turn or so.

Comment: If they don't sense it when it's not spinning then how do you get the motor to start in the first place without spinning it by hand?

Comment: _"Here is the schematic"_ - there are no Hall sensors in that schematic. Please show us how you have the sensors hooked up.

Comment: Schematic link is broken. Generally, hall sensor output is open drain. That means, you should pull up high for each phase. Supply the hall sensors(generally 5V), spin the motor, sure about pull up for each output exist, outputs  should be high or low for magnet rotation, respectively.

Comment: So I used a pull up resistor like @mrsaglam recommended and the sensors seems to be working now, but I have another problem that the sensors are reading high / low depending on the orientation of the motor even when I have completely unplugged the motor. But I guess I should ask this on a different question.

Comment: Per previous comment : you can run the motor open-loop to start it.

Comment: the permanent magnets don't need power to work! Therefore the hall sensors will detect position whether the motor is powered or not.